# SQL Query to Concat output

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

I have an addition SQL question, hopefully someone here can give me a hand.

I have the following mysql table:

```
ID  Type     Result
1   vinyl    blue, red, green
1   leather  purple, orange
2   leather  yellow
```

and i am seeking the following output:

```
ID Row One                 Row Two
1  vinyl blue, red, green  leather purple, orange
2  leather yellow
```

the thing is... type is not static... there are many different types and not all of them have the same ones.  They need to follow in order.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question isn't very coherent.  For instance what does "not all of them have the ones" mean?

Comment: I apologize, let me try to clarify.  There is a column called type in the original table; it can have a wide range of values.  Not all ID's have the same types.  For each ID in the table it needs to be able to create a new column for each type and concat the result and type together in there.

I hope this makes atleast some sense.

Answer (score 1):

Please post a show create table of your table. It's not clear what you mean in fact.

Maybe what you need is GROUP_CONCAT after all:

```
mysql> select ID, GROUP_CONCAT(type,' ',result) from test;
```

Let us know.